# Can neo4j dijkstra get all shortest path for a node?

Tags: neo4j

I learned from book than use dijkstra can get all shortest path between a given node and others. But I found I just get shortest path between two node using neo4j dijkstra.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *Neo4j* *dijkstra* can get all shortest paths for a node.

Quoted from [the Neo4j Manual v2.3.1](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-and-get-multiple-paths):

> Note that the request URI ends with `/paths` which means we want multiple paths returned, in case they exist.

Comment: It's all shortest path between node A and node B, but I want to get shortest path between A and B, A and C, A and ... in one dijkstra compute